# Why no "field is never assigned" warning with @Mock

Tags: java, intellij-idea, annotations, mockito

If you declare a private field in a test class:

`private Foo foo;`

That gets used but is never assigned, IntelliJ IDEA (and presumably other IDEs) show a warning when I hover over the declaration, and it renders it gray

**private field 'foo' is never assigned**

But if I'm using Mockito and annotate the field like:

`@Mock
private Foo foo;`

The warning disappears and renders the field in purple to indicate that it is assigned. How does the IDE know what `@Mock` implies? I've had a look through the Mockito source code and there doesn't seem to be anything on the annotation definition and my IDE doesn't have a Mockito plugin.

I'm writing a library similar to Mockito with an equivilant annotation and I'd love to know to get the IDE to remove the warning.

(I'm not a Java developer, so if I've said anything wrong please correct me)

**EDIT**
I've tried this in Eclipse and it actually removes the warning with any annotation, which is what @nikpon was suggesting.

Comment: `private` fields are always assigned to a default value.  I've seen the "foo is never assigned" in reference to _local variables_, but never _fields_.

Comment: In IntelliJ I'm definitely getting the warning on a field. The color of the unassigned field is gray, but turns purple when @Mock is applied to it (and the warning message goes away).

Comment: That's just weird.  Maybe IntelliJ maintains a list of "auto-populate" annotations so that it can modify this warning behavior.  Technically, there is no such thing as an unassigned field, so I would never expect to see this warning ever.  If I saw it on `@Mock` or `@Autowired` fields it would drive me nuts.  Perhaps they "fixed" that for such cases.

Comment: Yes my assumption was that Mockito is so ubiquitous that it just special cases @Mock which would be a shame for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "unused symbol" inspection in IntelliJ IDEA has special configuration for this annotation.

A quick search for "org.mockito.Mock" in the [intellij-community](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community) code base reveals the [JUnitEntryPoint](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/995ac2bc094309246317a5e0e16d0710632566c2/plugins/junit/src/com/intellij/execution/junit2/inspection/JUnitEntryPoint.java) class, which plugs into the "deadCode" extension point.

The entry points contributed through this mechanism are in turn queried by inspections like [UnusedDeclarationInspection](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/66ddb299c8deedf1c9e25ffb27888ba1b45a607b/java/java-analysis-impl/src/com/intellij/codeInspection/deadCode/UnusedDeclarationInspection.java).

Note that the inspection has a configuration pane where you can configure additional custom annotations that should prevent a field from being marked as unused.

You can access this configuration from *Settings->Inspections*, then search for the "unused symbol" inspection by name:
[screenshot of the "unused symbol" inspection configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1ya6.png)

For convenience, you can also navigate to these settings directly, by invoking *Alt-Enter* while the caret is on a field marked as unused by IDEA:
[screenshot of accessing the "unused symbol" settings by invoking Alt-Enter on an unused field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yD21V.png)

Comment: Hmm, isn't this only half a solution to the problem? I'd like to have IntelliJ warn me when I declare a @Mock member variable, but never use it, which is not possible...

Comment: Good point. I've filed [IDEA-118095](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-118095) to improve this. Please take a look and add your comments.