# Used field "is never assigned" in InellijIdea with @FindBy annotation

Tags: java, intellij-idea

How can I resolve this issue in IntellijIdea?

[image]

This answer [Why no "field is never assigned" warning with @Mock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19732929/why-no-field-is-never-assigned-warning-with-mock) only describe the reason but not offer the resolving.

Comment: What does `resetField` do?

Comment: @Sweeper This is not important. Those fields (@FindBy annotated) do "never assigned" in all classes and all methods.

Comment: did u check this https://www.igorkromin.net/index.php/2018/08/23/how-to-suppress-unused-method-inspection-in-intellij-for-a-specific-method/  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166334/disable-not-used-warning-for-public-methods-of-a-class

Comment: @pvpkiran Done! You can be answered with this resolving, I will accept it. https://www.igorkromin.net/index.php/2018/08/23/how-to-suppress-unused-method-inspection-in-intellij-for-a-specific-method/

Comment: Gr8. I haven't done anything. I do not deserve the point :) The answer was from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166334/disable-not-used-warning-for-public-methods-of-a-class. Just upvote there. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This warning is produced by the "Unused declaration" inspection, which does not know about the `@FindBy` annotation. To teach it, position the text cursor on the name of the field, type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and invoke the `Suppress unused warning if annotated by '@FindBy'` action. After that it will no longer warn on any field annotated by this annotation.

The action will add the intention to an internal "Mark field as implicitly written if annotated by" list. The setting can also be found in the settings of the inspection by clicking on the `Annotations...` button under the `Entry points` tab.

Answer (score 2):

To get rid of the warning you can add getter and setter for your fields.

```
public SelenideElement getOldPassword(){
    return this.oldPassword;
}

public void setOldPassword(SelenideElement oldPassword){
    this.oldPassword = oldPassword;
}
```